Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:
$ nest g resource employees
? What transport layer do you use? REST API
? Would you like to generate CRUD entry points? Yes
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')
Failed to execute command: node @nestjs/schematics:resource --name=employees --no-dry-run --no-skip-import --language="ts" --source-root="src" --spec --no-flat --spec-file-suffix="spec"
image with nest-cli-json and te terminal with error
I tried everything, can anyone help me?

Can you provide an image of your project structure and package.json dependencies

This question is similar to: Nestjs can’t generate. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
